# Reading Multiple Firebase Documents One By One

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So in my web application, I am fetching data from firebase, it will have about 5000 documents by the time it's ready. So to reduce the number of reads, I keep an array in firebase with a list of ids of each documents, which I read and then compare with the list I have saved locally. If an id is missing, I read that particular doc from firebase (Firebase website definitely slowed down with having an array with 3000 docs so far).

However, consider the situation where I have 2000+ docs missing and I have to fetch them one by one according to `missingList` I  created from comparing the firebase and local arrays. It is heck a lot of slow, it takes so long to fetch even a hundred documents because I am using await. If I don't, then firebase is overloaded with requests and for some reason it shows a warning that my net is disconnected.

What is the best way to fetch documents with ids given in an array, with no loss and reasonably fast enough? Is there a way for me to batch read documents like there is batch write, update and set?

Say Firebase has `[1234, 1235, 1236, 1237]` and I only have `[1234]` so I need to read `[1235, 1236, 1237]` from it.

I am using a for loop to iterate through each id and get the corresponding document like so

```
for (let i = 0; i < missingList.length; i++) {
  var item = await db.collection('myCollection').doc(missingList[i]).get().then((snapshot) => snapshot.data())
  await saveToDB(item) //I use PouchDB for local storage
}
```

Comment: how many user do you expect will be using the app at the same time?

Comment: @ThienLD Only one at the moment, it's tailor made for one user.

Comment: okay, then I think I have a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to a 'batched read' in Firestore is a transaction, but using a transation to read hundreds of document is not really efficient. Instead, I suggest you add one field to every document, like `token`. Then, every time you get data for the **first** time, generate a random token client-side, then write it to every document that you read. After that, if you detect a change in the list of ids you mention above, run a query on that `token` field, like :

```
db.collection('myCollection').where('token', '!=', locallySavedToken).get()
```

Remember to write your local token back to the read documents. This way, your query time will be much faster. The down side is you need 1 extra write request for every document read. If you need to re-read your data a lot then maybe look into transactions, since write requests pricing is more expensive than read requests

Comment: you get 20k free write request per day, so unless you need more than that you don't need transactions

Comment: Whoa, this will work more better than what I currently coded. I will go with that token method. I currently don't have to worry about exceeding the 20000 write limit, I am pretty sure I won't cross it. Thanks!

Comment: @RohitV glad i could help

Comment: The number of reads is equal to the number of documents the condition is satisfied for right?

Comment: yes, for example if you get 10 documents it counts as 10 reads